# PHP7.2 Undefined variable: option in .... index.php with Dj-Business004 template

Tags: php, templates, variable

When I update PHP from PHP7 to PHP7.2 the website gives this error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

This is in the Log file:

> [Thu Jan 24 04:44:56.061781 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 30185:tid 139984342161152] [client xxxxx] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: option in /home/xxxxx/domains/xxxxxxxxx.xx/public_html/templates/dj-business004/index.php on line 51\n'

Line 51 is:

```
if ($option && isset($sideBarsScheme[$option]) && trim($sideBarsScheme[$option]) && stristr($sideBarsScheme[$option],'content')!= false){
```

This is the code line 51 - 55:

```
if ($option && isset($sideBarsScheme[$option]) && trim($sideBarsScheme[$option]) && stristr($sideBarsScheme[$option],'content')!= false){
    $currentScheme = trim($sideBarsScheme[$option]);
} else {
    $currentScheme = $sideBarsScheme['default'];
}
```

How can I repair this?

Comment: Where is `$option` being defined? Please search for `$option = ` and show the code for this in your question

Comment: In the index.php file I don't see any other place where $option is shown apart from the lines I showed above. Is it helpful when I paste the complete index.php code?

Comment: I would like to state as a matter of best practice that condition 3 doesn't make sense to implement because condition 4 will include this check (of course the trimmed value will be non-empty if the existence of `content` is true.  Also, when checking for the existence of a substring (and not actually extracting the substring), best practice dictates that you should not be calling `strstr()` or `stristr()`, but rather `strpos()` or `stripos()`.  This advice is specifically noted in the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php (see 2nd Note)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've just taken a look at the code for your template and it looks like a Joomla 1.5 template.

If you're using Joomla 1.5, PHP 7.2 isn't supported at all. I'd strongly suggest migrating to Joomla 3.x

If you already are using Joomla 3.x, then the `$option` simply isn't defined anywhere in your `index.php` or `menu.php`. Perhaps the PHP 7.0 version you had supressed all errors, not sure but it needs fixing.

The issue being is I have no idea what `$option` is supposed to be.

Based on the following code on your template:

```
$sideBarsScheme = array (
    //by default
    'default'=>      'left-right-content',

    // specify extra options for different components
    // if you dont write left or right - these positions wont be published
    // left-right-content | right-left-content | content-right-left | content-left-right
    // left-content-right | right-content-left
    // right-content | content-left | left-content | content-right
    'com_contact'=>  'content',
    'com_search'=>  'content-left-right',
    'com_content'=>  'left-content-right',
    'com_frontpage'=> 'left-content-right'

);
```

I believe this was originally a Joomla 1.0 template which was updated to support 1.5

So you have 2 options:

**Option 1:** Use a new (HTML5) template that utilises the Joomla API and was build fro Joomla 3.x

**Option 2:** Add the following line of code to the top of your `index.php`, just above the big block of code I shared above:

```
$option = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('option');
```

Comment: The website/template is using the latest Joomla version J3.9.2

Comment: It is a very old template, that's right.

Comment: I added $option = $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('option'); and on PHP7 the error is not shown anymore. On PHP7.2 the homepage still gives a 500 error. Other pages give 0 - [] operator not supported for strings. I checked if $field->html = ''; is in index.php file but it's not there.

Comment: I would choose option 1 :)

Comment: @Joflx sorry I made a mistake in the code, please copy and paste it again

Comment: I changed the code, no difference.

Comment: I understand you would choose option 1 but the website will go offline within 6 month. Therefore I won't change to a complete new template. I am looking for a solution to keep it going on HP7.2 because of safety issues of PHP7.0. I hope you can help me further...

Comment: @Joflx - you changed the code as Lodder suggested and it solved the original error of your question  and you got a new error and then you solved that new error as per your answer... just to put it precisely :)

Comment: Well, never mind...

Answer (score -1):

I set debug in configuration file to 1 and opened another page (not homepage that only gave 500 error)
The other page showed this error:
0 - [] operator not supported for strings
[] operator not supported for strings
/home/xxx/domains/xxx.xx/public_html/templates/dj-business004/index.php:68

Call stack

## Function    Location

1   ()  JROOT/templates/dj-business004/index.php:68

I replaced

$schemeOutput = '';

by

$schemeOutput = array();

and the issue was solved. Website works on PHP7.2 now.

Comment: It's nice that finally you've found another error and corrected an expected array in the code, but your original question was totally different. So this is not an answer on your original question...

Comment: Wellllllll..... It *is* the answer to the 500 error in the original question. The $option stuff was a Notice, not an Error, so it wouldn't have caused the 500, unless there's something non-default in the PHP configuration file.